# adding a textview to scrolledwindow in pygtk

Tags: python, linux, gtk, pygtk, glade

I am trying to add some text into a scrolledwindow in pygtk. The textview is packed inside a simple box container. I searched online and came to know that I need to first add a viewport in order for this to work but I keep getting the following error:

`Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_viewport_add: assertion 'gtk_bin_get_child (bin) == NULL' failed`

Here is my code:

```
container = Gtk.Box()
container.set_name('text_container')

tv = Gtk.TextView()
text_input = self.builder.get_object('entry1')
text = text_input.get_text()
text_input.set_text('')
tv.get_buffer().set_text(text)

container.pack_start(tv,True,True,0)
self.viewport.add(container)
```

I've followed this method because i already added a viewport to the scrolled window in my "glade" file. Any help or online resources are welcomed.

Comment: Have you tried just adding the TextView directly to the ScrolledWindow? That's how I have it in one of my scripts.

Comment: @SiHa yes i did and that works, but it does not fulfill my requirement. It is a simple chat window and i want to want to pack each message in a container just like we do with <div>/<span> in html. Moreover I packed it inside a box because i wanted to apply my custom CSS on it as explained here [link](http://wolfvollprecht.de/blog/gtk-python-and-css-are-an-awesome-combo/) using the .set_name('mywindow') to work as id selector.

Comment: Ah. Does answer below help then?

Comment: You can't instantiate `Gtk.Box`, it's abstract. Instead, choose one of `Gtk.VBox` or `Gtk.HBox`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with an HBox/VBox, that was the only problem there. However now that I have used the add_with_viewport() method, on which object should I be calling the show() method in order for my added widget to be shown?
here is the final code:-

```
container = Gtk.VBox()
container.set_name('text_container')
tv = Gtk.TextView()
text_input = self.builder.get_object('entry1')
text = text_input.get_text()
if text:
        text_input.set_text('')
        tv.get_buffer().set_text(text)

        container.pack_start(tv,True,True,0)
        self.sw.add_with_viewport(container)
```

since no there is no variable referencing to the just added viewport, on which object shall I call the show() method for the widget to be displayed in the scrolledwindow. I tried adding show to the container like `container.show()`but it didn't show up.

Comment: If I answered your question above, would you mind marking it as answered? Posting a different question as an answer isn't really the best way of getting maximum exposure for the new question, I only stumbled upon it by chance. To answer your **second** question, try `show_all()` to show a widget and all its children. Unless you are hiding and showing different widgets, the easiest thing is to call `show_all` on the top-level window after everything has been defined.

Answer (score 2):

Missed the real reason first time round.

The problem is that you are adding more than one widget to the viewport (which can only have one widget).

`gtk_viewport_add: assertion 'gtk_bin_get_child (bin) == NULL' failed`

Translates to: "The assertion that the viewport has no children is false", because you've already added something.

You need to pack all your containers into another container, and *then* add that to the viewport.

Comment: No. I have tried this before and tried this now as well.
I get the following error:-

 Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_scrolled_window_add_with_viewport: assertion 'gtk_bin_get_child (GTK_BIN (child_widget)) == NULL' failed
here is my code now :-
<pre>
def on_button1_clicked(self,button):
 container = Gtk.Box()
 container.set_name('text_container')
 tv = Gtk.TextView()
 text_input = self.builder.get_object('entry1')
 text = text_input.get_text()
 text_input.set_text('')
 tv.get_buffer().set_text(text)

 container.pack_start(tv,True,True,0)
 self.sw.add_with_viewport(container)
<code>
*using gi.repository